# Angular single observable, multiple observers

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

learning angular got to services and component and observables.

I'm trying to implement a dark mode in my demo app. The control is done by a service which sets the dark theme based on the browser default if found.

Its initialized in the app component to later have control switches to be placed in the app.

The dark mode works from a boolean value so either true or false. As I understand using an observable isnt enough as I want multiple subscribers to all bind two ways to the subscription each in a different way toggling these observable in the service. I'm pretty sure that's correct so far.

The part I'm stuck. Say if you want 3 different components a button component I the toolbar, a checkbox in the settings and toggle switch in users main settings for example.

How would you use make the 2 way link between the observable in the services and each component so that when each component emits the toggle event all update ? I'm pretty sure behaviourSubject or subject observables are the correct route to go but the angular docs really only go into single case use ? Unless I cant see it and further explanation in the difference of these observables seems to be limited as to the difference between them. One returning from the init value other now but not their implementation across multiple components

Do you have a global observable that the components all create individual observables on init to update the view.. I'm clueless.. it seems so simple yet when trying to out it in practice mind boggling.

Comment: RxJS Subject (and it's descendent) are multicast by default. Source observable could have multiple observers and they will all receive the notification when it's pushed to the source observable.

Comment: Yep, got most of the theory behind them so was along the right tracks but just couldn't work out how it would be implemented if the service would effectively have children subscribers the link the output to the component which in turn chains up to the parent or direct interaction sort of thing.. guy below got what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to share an observable between multiple components, and have each component listen to it and modify it by toggling on/off?

You could use a singleton service and subscribe to the subject in your components? This stackblitz is fairly crude, but its an example of separate components updating a single shared source observable. In this case it doesn't have to use a BehaviorSubject either, can just do a regular subject. Behavior subject could be useful to default to light mode if you wanted to.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ox4utu

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant, and so i theory if the initial value was set in the app controller ontop of the unreadable initial value then still wouldnt need behaviourSubject either ? Only other thing to ask is why the $ at the ends? First time I've seen bare In mind newbie :)

Comment: @JasonDemitri Yeah, so you could make it a subject and in app component do `darkModeValueService.updateMode(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)` or something. But, that could also be done in the constructor of the singleton service I believe - if you don't need any other variables in app component. The `$` at the end is just a convention my team uses to identify observable objects vs plain variables. E.G. we would do something like `currentMode: Mode`, `currentMode$: Observable<Mode>` or `Subject<Mode>`